# Angular Firebase how to retrieve single object from AngularFirestoreCollection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an application with Angular for client side and Firebase for back-end. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve a single object from  AngularFirestore. But unfortunately the server response with a empty array and with

`Object { initialTeardown: undefined, closed: false, _parentage: null, _finalizers: (1) […], isStopped: false, destination: {…} }`

This is my estateService file, all other methods works only the method `getById()` didn't works as expected

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Estate } from '../models/estate.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EstateService {
  private dbPath = '/estates';

  estatesRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Estate>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.estatesRef = db.collection(this.dbPath);
  }

  getAll(): AngularFirestoreCollection<Estate> {
    return this.estatesRef;
  }

  getById(estateId: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Estate> {
    return this.db.collection<Estate>('estates', ref => ref.where('id', '==', estateId));
  }

  getByUser(userId: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Estate> {
    return this.db.collection<Estate>('estates', ref => ref.where('owner', '==', userId));
  }

  create(estate: Estate): any {
    return this.estatesRef.add({...estate});
  }

  update(id: string, data: any): Promise<void> {
    return this.estatesRef.doc(id).update(data);
  }

  delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.estatesRef.doc(id).delete();
  }

}
```

And this is the estate-details component where I'm trying to implement and use the single object.

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-estate-details',
  templateUrl: './estate-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./estate-details.component.scss'],
})
export class EstateDetailsComponent {
  estate: Estate | undefined;

  constructor(
    private estateService: EstateService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.fetchSingleEstate();
  }

  fetchSingleEstate(): void {
    this.estate = undefined;
    const estateId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    const estateAr = this.estateService.getById(estateId);
    console.log(
      estateAr.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map((changes) =>
          changes.map((e) => ({
            ...(e.payload.doc.data() as Estate),
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
          }))
        )
      ).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    );
  }
}

this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'] returns the correct Id. I searched for a information but  didn't find any solution that works in my case.
```

All checked solutions : [Angular | Get one row from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366225/angular-get-one-row-from-firebase), [How i can get single record with ID](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1142), [How to get one doc by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223306/how-to-get-one-document-by-id-angular-4-firestore),
[Docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research the following do the job for me. Instead of new request to the server I've created a `setActive()` method in the objects list component. And whit this method I'm just taking the `currentObject` and the `currentObjectIndex`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-estates',
  templateUrl: './estates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./estates.component.scss'],
  animations: [pageAnimations]
})
export class EstatesComponent implements OnInit {
  arrayEstate?: Estate[];

  currentEstate?: Estate;
  currentIndex = -1;

  constructor(
    private estateService: EstateService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.retrieveEstates()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  refreshList(): void { // Used to set the active estate to null
    this.currentEstate = undefined;
    this.currentIndex = -1;
    this.retrieveEstates();
  }

  setActiveEstate(estate: Estate, index: number): void {
    this.currentEstate = estate;
    this.currentIndex = index;
  }

}
```

And just passing the current estate to the child component(Which in my case is EstateDetailsComponent) using the `@Input` decorator. And with the help of the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook just listen for changes in the `currentObject` value. If any changes just pass them to the `currentEstate` property in my child component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-estate-details',
  templateUrl: './estate-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./estate-details.component.scss'],
  // animations: [bounceIn],
})
export class EstateDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() estate?: Estate;
  @Output() refreshList: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild(NgForm, { static: true }) form!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  currentEstate: Estate = {
    address: '',
    city: '',
    zip: '',
    bedrooms: 0,
    baths: 0,
    type: '',
    price: 0,
    rented: true,
    maintenance: false,
  };

  constructor(private estateService: EstateService) {}

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.currentEstate = { ...this.estate };
  }

  updateEstate(form: NgForm): void { //Edit single object
    const data = {
      id: this.currentEstate.id,
      owner: this.currentEstate.owner,
      ...form.value,
    };

    if (this.currentEstate.id) {
      this.estateService
        .update(this.currentEstate.id, data)
        .then(() => this.toggleEditMode())
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }


  unsetEstate(): void {
    this.refreshList.emit();
  }

}
```

This is a way more flexible than taking the single object with server request. Hope someone else find this helpful too.